# Pandas - scoring column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data about product sales (1 column per product) at the customer level (1 row per customer).
I'm assessing which customers are more likely to be interested in a specific product. I have a list of the 10 most correlated products. (and I have this for multiple products, so I'm trying to build a scalable approach).
I'm trying to score all customers based on how many of those 10 products they buy.

Let's say my list is:
prod_x_corr_prod

How can I create a scoring column (say prox_x_propensity) which goes through the 10 relevant columns, for every row, and for each column with a value > 0 adds 1?

For instance, if customer Y bought 3 of the products correlated with product X, he would have a score of 3 in the "prox_x_score" column.

EDIT: thanks to all of you for the feedback.

For customer 5 I would ge a 2, while for 1,2,3 I would get 1. For 4, 0.

Comment: Without a sample data and expected output, it's hard to understand what you want.

Comment: It looks like an interesting question. But you should build a minimal sample, so that we can have a relevant dataset to process... You should also give the sizes of the actual data for other to have a hint on what tools can be used.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users. You haven't even provided a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks to you too for the helpful answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:
`df['prox_x_score'] = (df[prod_x_corr_prod] > 0).sum(axis=1)`

Example with dummy data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

prod_x_corr_prod = ["prod{}".format(i) for i in range(1, 11)]

df = pd.DataFrame({col:np.random.choice([0,1], size=5) for col in prod_x_corr_prod})

df['prox_x_score'] = (df[prod_x_corr_prod] > 0).sum(axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   prod1  prod10  prod2  prod3  prod4  prod5  prod6  prod7  prod8  prod9  \
0      1       1      1      0      0      1      1      1      1      0   
1      1       1      1      0      1      0      0      1      1      0   
2      1       1      1      1      0      1      0      0      1      0   
3      0       0      0      0      0      0      1      0      1      0   
4      0       0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      0   
   prox_x_score  
0             7  
1             6  
2             6  
3             2  
4             2
```